# How to supply power to a 12V solenoid from China, getting hot

Tags: resistors, solenoid, 12v

I bought [this solenoid from ebay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/400665025724?ssPageName=STRK%3aMEWNX%3aIT&_trksid=p3984.m1497.l2649) and was wondering how to power it.

It says 12 volts as you can also see from the picture, but I tested it with putting a 9V battery straight to its terminals for a while, the solenoid and battery got hot after a while.

I measured it with a multimeter and it read 9.0 ohms. Putting the multimeter through it measured 0.53 amps. Both with 9V battery

If I had battery eliminator that gave 12V output, what other components would I need to make it not go hot? Do I need some resistors?

And is it possible to get its power usage to a minimum with it still opening using various components?

Can I add lots of resistors and the voltage remains 12?

Comment: You could contact the manufacturer (from china [sic]) and ask them how to drive their solenoid, and why is it getting hot, and whether or not that is a problem.

Comment: It being April 1 now, I can only say that if you don't live in China you will need very long wires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the coil resistance is 9 ohms, it should draw 1.33 amps at 12 volts, and dissipate 16 watts - so it will get quite hot.  That current is much more than a common 9 volt battery can supply - from the current you mention, the battery voltage will be about 4.8 volts when trying to drive the valve.

Despite the eBay ad's claim, I suspect it may actually be an AC solenoid.  On one dealer's website, I see coil powers for that size valve stated as 3 - 6 watts.

Adding resistors in series with the coil won't help - it will just reduce the current, and the voltage across the coil.

Comment: If it is A DC solenoid it may not be rated for continuous duty-  It might be intended to actuate something for a short time.  Without the manufacturer's data it's hard to know.

Comment: Yup, goes to show. I think i will buy a solenoid from another supplier with more info etc. Thanks!

Comment: @user6529  EE.SE golden rule: "No datasheet = No sale."

Comment: @user6529 and don't buy Chinese junk on eBay (or any electronic component really)

Answer (score 1):

Some solenoids current limit when switched correctly. Probably not this one, but you wouldn't know, would you? 9V is rather less than 10.8V, the rated minimum voltage.

Looking at it, I would guess that the way to keep it cool when switched open, is to run something like water through the valve when it is switched open.

Comment: But they are claim this valve it is suitable for Gas as well, or maybe can control hot water. Have you any data from manufacturer, or it is a guess?